# PHP AJAX Load previous data on Scroll Top

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, infinite-scroll

How can I load more (previous) data when the page is scrolled to top? I am creating a chat app where by default I am loading last 20 messages only, to avoid heavy load on the server. When the chat box is opened and messages are fetched, the users are scrolled to the bottom by default. I want to implement infinite scrolling but in the reverse order. When the users scroll to the top they can load more 20 messages and they can keep scrolling to load more messages until the reach the end.

My current query

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM (
                SELECT * 
                FROM messages 
                ORDER BY id DESC 
                LIMIT 20
            ) m
        WHERE (
                (msg_to = :omsg AND msg_from = :imsg) 
                OR 
                (msg_to = :imsg AND msg_from = :omsg)
            ) 
        AND (clear_by = 0 OR clear_by != :omsg)
        ORDER BY id ASC");
```

This query gives me last 20 messages.

My Jquery

```
$('.chat-box').scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // PREPEND OLD MESSAGES IN CHAT ON SCROLL TOP
    if(st <= 10){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processes/chat.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'type=loadmore&to='+to,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                $(".retrive-chat").prepend(data.html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like any other pagination/infinite scroll, but you have DESC instead of ASC in the query? And that you need to reverse the order for the result you get.

Comment: @M.Eriksson What about how it will know what was the last id fetched (from top) to get more data previous to that id ? For example, suppose I have loaded 20 msgs from id 81-100. Now when I scroll to top it should fetch 61-80. So, how do I track 81 here to get previous data?

Comment: Just have a JS variable that you add 20 (or your "per page" value) to for each time you fetch more data.

Comment: @M.Eriksson No not that value. I mean the `id` of the last fetched record.